# While building android project multiple tasks depends on output of another task

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, gradlew

':app:processDebugMainManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts'
':app:mergeExtDexDebug' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts'
':app:mergeDebugJavaResource' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts'

react-native version 0.72.7 and tried with gradle versions above 8.0

I have upgraded all the files as  per react-native version. want to know where I am wrong. I tried to explicitly define tasks dependency even that also not worked. got error this task already exist.